# Trying to install Gitolite and running into File::Path module issue

Tags: git, gitolite

Trying to install Gitolite on a Media Temple DV server [following these instructions](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/nonroot.html). As soon as I get to the `gitolite/src/gl-system-install` line I receive this error:

```
"make_path" is not exported by the File::Path module
Can't continue after import errors at gitolite/src/gl-system-install line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at gitolite/src/gl-system-install line 5.
```

Not sure how to take care of this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you don't have that Perl module installed on your system.  Which modules are installed by default varies from OS to OS.

Try installing this module from CPAN and see if the issue persists.  It is possible this is not the only Perl module that is missing, so if it complains of a subsequent Perl module problem, satisfy each subsequent requirement in the same way.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path](http://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aPath)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your system installation is just too old. You need at least File::Path >= 2.07 for make_path. perl-5.12 is the first to version to satisfy this requirement.